# vba code to get next element from webpage with same class

Tags: vba, selenium

```
Sub Class_Initialize()
Set driver = CreateObject("Selenium.FirefoxDriver")
driver.Get "https://www.99acres.com/3-bhk-bedroom-apartment-flat-for-sale-in-sunworld-vanalika-sector-107-noida-1405-sq-ft-spid-K34257367?pos=SEARCH&fsl=Y"
driver.Window.Maximize
Dim dd As Variant
dd = driver.findElementByClass("pdFactVal").Text
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = dd

dd = driver.findElementByClass("pdFactVal").Item(2).Text
Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = dd
End Sub
```

Hi,
i have a page opened in selenium vba, and in this page i have a lot of elements with the same class name, and when i get this element with the code: `dd = driver.findElementByClass("pdFactVal").Text` it returns to me the first element in page in column A its fine but i want the element number 2 in column B and i use code `dd = driver.findElementByClass("pdFactVal").Item(2).Text` here i am getting error-Run time error '438' Object doesn't support this property of method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of findElementByclass,  You can use findElementsByClass.

```
dd = driver.findElementsByClass("pdFactVal").Item(2).Text
```

Comment: Hi Murthi thanks for the reply i have use your code and i am getting error-Run time error '438' Object doesn't support this property of method.

Comment: sorry, there is findElementsByClass is there in vba selenium. you can try that.